# Copy filtered cell by color on another sheet without header

Tags: excel, vba

i have the below code to filter from a sheet the yellow cells in column A and copy them on another sheet at the bottom of the values already present in the column A, however also the header is beeing copied and i need to exclude it, what's wrong in your opinion?

```
Sub CopyColor()



Dim wk As Workbook: Set wk = ThisWorkbook
Dim sht As Worksheet: Set sht = wk.Worksheets("Base Dati Old")
Dim sht1 As Worksheet: Set sht1 = wk.Worksheets("Prova")
Dim lr, lr1 As Long, rng As Range




'Define last used row;
lr = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lr1 = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = sht.Range("A2:A" & lr)

'Filter your data on yellow;
rng.AutoFilter 1, RGB(255, 255, 0), xlFilterCellColor

'Copy filtered cells;
rng.SpecialCells(12).Offset.Copy wk.Worksheets("Prova").Range("A" & lr1)



'Turn off filter
rng.AutoFilter



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
rng.Offset(1,0).Resize(rng.Rows.count-1).SpecialCells(12).Copy _
       wk.Worksheets("Prova").Range("A" & lr1)
```